# upgrade from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04

i want to upgrade my (german) desktop from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS but get no chance. My software updater says my 12.04 is actual and that's it.

Comment: How did you upgrade your ubuntu? hold the SHIFT key during boot to go to [ubuntu grub](http://namhuy.net/1963/change-default-os-ubuntu-windows-grub-dual-boot-setup.html), choose advanced ubuntu then go to recovery mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

- Open Teminal and apply updates for current version

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```
- Now do the Ubuntu upgrade

  ```
  sudo do-release-upgrade
  ```

Answer (score 0):

First update your Ubuntu 12.04.

Open Terminal Ctr + Alt + T

Type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Next step is to update to 14.04 by use this command:

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

Than just follow the Install Instructions.

Source: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04

**Answer in German / Antwort auf Deutsch:**

öffne das Terminal mit:

Strg + Alt + T

Update dein aktuelles system mit disem Befehl:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Starte die Installation von 14.04 mit diesem Befehl:

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

folge den installations Anweisungen

Quelle: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04

Answer (score 0):

to [upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://namhuy.net/2853/upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-lts-ubuntu-14-04-lts.html)

Boot up and login to your Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 system. On your keyboard, press “Alt+F2″, and type in “update-manager” without the quotes. On Update Manger window, click “Check” to check for new update. After the checking finished, you shoud see “New Ubuntu release ’14.04′ is available”, and “Upgrade” button next to the line. All you have to do now is to click on “Upgrade” button to upgrade your Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.